# How can I split a PDF in Google cloud storage?

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, pdf-generation, cloud-document-ai

I have a single PDF that I would like to create different PDFs for each of its pages. How would I be able to so without downloading anything locally? I know that Document AI has a file splitting module (which would actually identify different files. That would be most ideal) but that is not available publicly.

I am using PyPDF2 to do this curretly

```
list_of_blobs = list(bucket.list_blobs(prefix = 'tmp/'))
print(len(list_of_blobs))
list_of_blobs[1].download_to_filename('/' + list_of_blobs[1].name)

inputpdf = PdfFileReader(open('/' + list_of_blobs[1].name, "rb"))

individual_files = []
stream = io.StringIO()

for i in range(inputpdf.numPages):
    output = PdfFileWriter()
    output.addPage(inputpdf.getPage(i))
    individual_files.append(output)
    with open("document-page%s.pdf" % (i + 1), "a") as outputStream:
        outputStream.write(stream.getvalue())
        #print(outputStream.read())
        with open(outputStream.name, 'rb') as f:
            data = f.seek(85)
            data = f.read()
            individual_files.append(data)
            bucket.blob('processed/' +  "doc%s.pdf" % (i + 1)).upload_from_string(data, content_type='application/pdf')
```

In the output, I see different PyPDF2 objects such as
`<PyPDF2.pdf.PdfFileWriter object at 0x12a2037f0>` but I have no idea how I should proceed next.

Comment: why you don't want to dowload original file locally?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere all of this would be happening in a cloud function

Comment: And the memory limit of Cloud Function is too small? What are the max size of your PDF file to split?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I am not splitting the PDF because of memory limit, I am splitting it because I need access to individual files within the large PDF separately. what I have is pdf1, pdf2, pdf3, etc. in a single large PDF, but I want to split them up into individual pdf1, pdf2, pdf3 files so that I can just process them as individual files. So I want to split pages if it makes sense

Comment: Yes, understood. But your concern is to not download the file from storage. My question is why? Do you have technical limits? like the memory limit? other reasons?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I am not downloading locally because the data is stored in GCS and the process that I want to run will be deployed in a google cloud function. So the best I can download the file is in a temp folder within the GCS bucket that already houses the files. The program will be automatically triggered whenever files are dropped into the bucket, and there is no need for any human to interact/trigger the program whatsoever. I have no issues downloading the file.. I just dont see the point in downloading it locally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were two reasons why my program was not working:

1. I was trying to read a file in append mode (I fixed this by moving the second `with(open)` block outside of the first one,
2. I should have been writing bytes (I fixed this by changing the open mode to 'wb' instead of 'a')

Below is the corrected code:

```
if inputpdf.numPages > 2:
   for i in range(inputpdf.numPages):
      output = PdfFileWriter()
      output.addPage(inputpdf.getPage(i))
      with open("/tmp/document-page%s.pdf" % (i + 1), "wb") as outputStream:
           output.write(outputStream)
      with open(outputStream.name, 'rb') as f:
           data = f.seek(0)
           data = f.read()
           #print(data)
           bucket.blob(prefix + '/processed/' +  "page-%s.pdf" % (i + 1)).upload_from_string(data, content_type='application/pdf')
      stream.truncate(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

To split a PDF file in several small file (page), you need to download the data for that. You can materialize the data in a file (in the writable directory `/tmp`) or simply keep them in memory in a python variable.

In both cases:

- The data will reside in memory
- You need to get the data to perform the PDF split.

---

If you absolutely want to read the data in streaming (I don't know if it's possible with PDF format!!), you can use the [streaming feature of GCS](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/streaming). But, because there isn't CRC on the downloaded data, I won't recommend you this solution, except if you are ready to handle corrupted data, retries and all related stuff.

Comment: thanks for your answer. could you check the updated code in my comment and see if that makes sense? I am able to now split PDFs and save them in my bucket, but the output PDFs seem to be corrupted

Comment: I'm not Python expert and I never handle PDF with Python (Typically, I don't know why you seek(85)). However, by looking at your code, I wondering if the data is a string or a byte array? you might have to convert the data output into a string format before sending it to storage. Have a try of this code locally, log the raw data that you have and try to find the sand grain which break the PDF format

Comment: yes, I was able to fix this finally and get what I wanted. To answer your question, data was a byte array. I was doing seek(85) because while troubleshooting I thought the issue in fixing a corrupted file had something to do with the byte array content - it wasn't so I changed it back. I'll post my code in a separate answer

Comment: @saladass4254 Please remember to create an answer with the fix for further readers to be able to fix further iterations of this issue.

Comment: @Roger I just added my answer

Answer (score 0):

FYI, Document AI has an actively monitored tag [`[cloud-document-ai]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloud-document-ai)

---

The [Document AI Toolbox SDK](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/toolbox) has been released as experimental, and it includes the ability to split PDF files based on the [output of a splitter/classifier processor](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/handle-response#splitting) in Document AI.

This documentation page lists the supported features and code samples.

https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/handle-response#toolbox